# App Speed in Google Analytics 3.03 iOS SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-analytics

I've seen a few posts around that previous versions <3.03 doesn't seem to work and I've tried all kinds of things now but this still doesn't appear to be working - nothing appears in the Behaviour/App Speed section of my GA

I'm using the iOS 3.03 GA SDK.  Here is my code:

```
- (void)onLoad:(NSTimeInterval *)loadTime {
    NSNumber *n = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:*loadTime*1000];
    NSLog(@"Time sent = %f ms", [n floatValue]);
    id tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];
    [tracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createTimingWithCategory:@"resources" interval:n     name:@"candidatesLoadTime" label:@"loadTime"] build]];
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help/advice

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have had the same issue as you for a while, but finally found the solution that worked for me!

It's not documented, as far as I can tell, but the `createTimingWithCategory:interval:name:label:` method takes the interval parameter as a `NSNumber` that is **required to be contain an `integer` value**

Try replacing the first row of your method with this:

```
NSNumber *n = [NSNumber numberWithInt:(int)(loadTime*1000)];
```

Credits go to [nh32rg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1005983/nh32rg) from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20126034/1652146)